# localhost rewrite

Tags: php, apache

I have wampserver set up on my machine and a website @ localhost/site/

I want to set up a local rewrite to where I can type in "somename" in my browser
and it resolves to localhost/site/

Can this be done in the hosts file? I am on windows 7 btw

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You can add the line `127.0.0.1 somename` to your HOSTS file, but it will only send you to `localhost`, you can't specify a folder for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can redirect any hostname to localhost via your hosts file. Put in:

```
127.0.0.1       my.site.com
```

No, you can't set the URL.

Answer (score 0):

in `DRIVE:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\httpd.conf`

change `ServerName localhost` to `ServerName somename`

try that,

IN THIS WAY, YOU CAN DIRECT LOCALHOST ( actually, we cant say this :P) to some othername

Answer (score 0):

### click on the server icon on the icon tray

[image]

then click on Apache then choose **Apache modules**

[image]

then click on mode_rewrite

then restart the server and it will be working